# Elastic Search Sub list filters

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elastic document, structured [simplified] like this:

```
{
 "Contest": {
   "Name": "Room1",
   "Participants": [
   {
    "PlayerID": "tester1",
    "Score": "30"
  },
  {
      "PlayerID": "tester2",
      "Score": "40"
    },
    {
      "PlayerID": "tester3",
      "Score": "10"
    }
  ]
}
```

}

How can I query this and get back a result, of the Contest, and only the Participant object with a Score of over 35?

When I query the object, and use a filter, I get back the entire list of participants, which is not what I need; I need a list only of the objects meeting the search criteria. Do I have to restructure with nested documents?

Answer (score 0):

Use [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html)  like :

```
{
"query": {
  "nested": {
     "path": "Participants",
     "query": {
      "range": {
         "Participants.score": {
            "from": 35
         }
      }
     },
     "inner_hits" : {}
     }
   }
 }
```

Fetch required results from `inner_hits`.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I had found, but just as a note: The output denormalize the structure, which I find to be less than ideal.

Comment: Did you find any other solution that does not denormalise the structure?